# Disallowing empty input

Tags: ios, swift, input, uitextfield, textfield

How do we disallow empty input on textField?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let oldText = textField.text!
    let stringRange = Range(range, in:oldText)!
    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)
    doneBarButton.isEnabled = !newText.isEmpty  
    return true
}
```

Is there other ways? or using other textField delegate methods to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is basically how you do it.

Alternatively, if all you want to know if the field is empty or not, just figure out the length of the result:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let length = (textField.text?.count ?? 0) + string.count - range.length
    doneBarButton.isEnabled = length > 0
    return true
}
```

You may also want to set [`enablesReturnKeyAutomatically`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1624432-enablesreturnkeyautomatically) for the text field to true, so that the keyboard doesn’t enable the “return” key unless there is text in the field.